# Which Interprocess Communication methods work on a Terminal Server?

Tags: sockets, ipc, named-pipes, terminal-services, dde

In a terminal server session, some standard IPC technologies might not work like in a single user environment, because the required **resources are not virtualized**.

For example, TCP/IP ports are not virtualized, so applications in different sessions which try to listen on the same port will cause a port conflict.

Which IPC technology will work in a terminal server environment where **applications running in the same user session** need to interact?

- Messages (WM_COPYDATA)?
- Named Pipes?
- DDE?
- Memory Mapped Files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Messages will work fine. [DDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648775(VS.85).aspx) will too, since it is based on messages. [Named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365783(VS.85).aspx) will not, since they are per-system and not per-session. You might also consider COM or OLE.

Answer (score 2):

All IPCs can be used in a TS environment - you just have to be clever in the naming of the objects to achieve the required end result. Using sockets is trickier but it can be done. I've listed a few methods below.

For IPC objects that can be named (Pipe, Event, Mutex, Memory Mapped File etc.) incorporating the session ID into the name of the object will achieve the *virtualisation* required.
To further lock down the IPC object use the object's security attributes to stop the possibility of any other user from accessing the IPC object. This could occur accidentally as a result of a bug or maliciously from another user on the terminal server.

Similarly use the logged on user's Authentication ID in the IPC object's name. In C++ see MSDN on [GetTokenInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446671(VS.85).aspx) use TokenStatistics for the TokenInformationClass. I'm sure there is an equivalent .NET method. Again secure the IPC object.

If you must use sockets on a TS (I personally would choose another method to communicate between applications on a TS) then use the port numbers. Pick a base port number and add the session number to get the port used for a session. To make sure that the correct applications are communicating use an authentication method and/or handshaking before transfering data. Theoretically sessions can be numbered up to 65535 so you may come unstuck when you use a base port number of say 2000 and session your application is run in session 65500.
If you really wanted to use sockets then maybe a broker service would help.